# Regex.Replace function with max-length

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm using the [Regex.Replace()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=netframework-4.8) function to only allow `Integers` on a `TextBox`.

> texbox.Text = Regex.Replace(texbox.Text, "[^0-9]", "");

Then I needed to add a `max-length = 4` on it, but it doesn't work.

> texbox.Text = Regex.Replace(texbox.Text, "[^0-9]{1,4}$", "");

I think I'm missing the logic but I couldn't solve it. I don't want to set the max-length of the textbox directly on its properties because I will need the whole input when the user uses the `copy-paste`.

Please refer to the code below for more details.

```
//Focus to Next Control when max-length > 4
private void FocusToNextTab(object sender){
    TextBox txtBox = (TextBox)this.ActiveControl;
    if (txtBox.TextLength > 4){
        this.SelectNextControl((Control)sender, true, true, true, true);    
    }
}


private void OnTextBoxChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){

    var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
    string original_text = textBox.Text; //I will need this on user copy-paste. 

    var cursorPosition = textBox.SelectionStart;
    textBox.Text = Regex.Replace(textBox.Text, "[^0-9]{1,4}$", "");
    textBox.SelectionStart = cursorPosition;

    FocusToNextTab(sender);      

    ...
}
```

Comment: You could use a custom control that accepts numbers only (e.g., call `int currentStyle = GetWindowLong(this.Handle, GWL_STYLE); SetWindowLong(this.Handle, GWL_STYLE, currentStyle | ES_NUMBER);` in `OnHandleCreated`). The ErrorProvider will also inform that the TextBox accepts numbers only. Then, handle `WM_PASTE`, to `SubString()` the Text and save the original paste. You're left with the text length. Many ways: it could be `if (textBox1.TextLength > 3 & (e.KeyValue > 39 & e.KeyCode != Keys.Delete)) { e.SuppressKeyPress = true; }` in the KeyDown event or handle the `WM_KEYDOWN` message or...

Comment: Use NumericUpDown instead of TextBox.

Comment: @Jimi - Can you tell me more?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov - The requirement is using the TextBox. NumericUpDown is only for numeric value. I need to handle the copy-paste and do something if it is not integers.

Comment: I mean, since you have multiple behaviors to handle, trying to solve all possible outcomes with a single method in an event handler is prone to errors and difficult to adapt when some conditions change. My suggestion is to create a specialized Custom Control that accepts numbers only (as descibed, or, better, setting the Style in `CreateParams`), handle `WM_PASTE` so you can predefine what happens when the string pasted in is > of a max Input value you can define with a property, then raise an event when the user pastes some text: the event will return the original text and the modified one.

Comment: If you think it could be interesting to see an *implemented* example, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have doubts this can be done with `Regex.Replace()`.

Alternatively you could match the string and concatenate the captured values.

```
string onlyFirstNDigits = "";
foreach (Capture capture in Regex.Match(textBox.Text, @"(?:\D*(?<digit>\d)){0,4}").Groups["digit"].Captures)
{
    onlyFirstNDigits += capture.Value;
}
textBox.Text = onlyFirstNDigits;
```

Or you could use a LINQ expression to select the first four characters, that are digits and concatenate them.

```
textBox.Text = string.Join("", textBox.Text.Where(c => Regex.Match(c.ToString(), @"^\d$").Success).Take(4));
```

Answer (score 0):

In your regex you should have

```
^[0-9]{1,4}
```

Maybe it will solve your issue.

Comment: It won't work without a dollar sign, and putting the caret outside the box bracket will reverse the condition.

Answer (score 0):

[TextBox.MaxLength](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.textbox.maxlength?view=netframework-4.8) seems to be made for this job.

Comment: Yes. But in my condition I need to handle the copy-paste or the original input whatever the length of it, I won't be able to handle it if max-length is set on the properties of the TextBox because it wont allow to have anything more than the max-length.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that in this case it is much easier to do without regular expressions.

```
var textBox = (TextBox)sender;

string text = string.Concat(
    textBox.Text.Where(c => char.IsDigit(c)).Take(4)
);

var cursorPosition = textBox.SelectionStart;
textBox.Text = text;
textBox.SelectionStart = cursorPosition;
```